# How to form this Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Suppose the string is:

```
string item = "t-ewrwerwerwerwer\r-rr\wrjkwlr";
```

I want to Replace all - except when it is preceded by r.

So resut will be

```
string cleanItem = "tewrwerwerwerwer\r-rr\wrjkwlr"'
```

What regular expression can be used?

Comment: replace all with what? String.Replace might be enough without having to create a regex.

Comment: Your 'r' in that case is preceded by an unescaped \, and therefore the two together really make one carriage return.

Comment: @SnOrfus, You can replace by any character
@joel, r can be any other character like f.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A replacement on `(?<!r)-` by an empty string should do the trick I think.

Answer (score 4):

I think this regular expression is a little more efficient:

```
-(?<!r-)
```

Or if your language doesn’t support negative look-behind assertions, use this expression:

```
(^|[^r])-
```

and replace it by `\1` (first matching group).

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<!r)-
```

As long as your regex flavor supports zero-width look-behind, that is.